# If I take the time to make a Java bean class, will it always work over Axis2?

Tags: java, soap, javabeans, apache-axis

I'm more or less a noob in the world of actually programming Java in the wild (spent my first 5 years out of college doing Delphi, but most of college programming Java - never encountered a bean there...)

So, I'm wondering why it's such a crapshoot as to whether the classes that I write wind up being properly imported into my WSDLs (using Rad Studio XE2).  I stumbled upon one of my old text books (probably from Java 1.5 days) where it talks about what goes into the bean standard and I'm just wondering, not for the sake of wondering, but because I really want to not shoot myself in the foot for the 7th time this year, if I make a legit bean, is it definitely going to work with Axis2?

I ask because I was just about to put this:

```
private final Queue<Runnable> updateEvents;
```

in the class I wanted to run through the SOAP and I had this sinking feeling like that wasn't going to work so well as a `TRemotable` object in Delphi.